# Does CloudFormation only support "Type": "String" when declaring parameters?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

When you declare parameters in CloudFormation, you have to set a "Type". In my experiments, "String" seems to be the only supported value. If that is true, what is the purpose of this attribute?

In the [AWS Documentation on parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack-parameters.html), it is not mentioned which values are supported for the "Type". It contains an example, however, that indicates that there is no integer type. The "WebServerPort" is also declared as "String", although ports are always integers:

```
"Parameters" : {
   "InstanceType" : {
      "Type" : "String",
      "Default" : "m1.small",
      "Description" : "EC2 instance type, e.g. m1.small, m1.large, etc."
   },
   "WebServerPort" : {
      "Type" : "String",
      "Default" : "80",
      "Description" : "TCP/IP port of the web server"
   },
   "KeyName" : {
      "Type" : "String",
      "Description" : "Name of an existing EC2 KeyPair to enable SSH access to the web server"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides `String`, there is `Number`, `List<Number>`, `CommaDelimitedList`, and a variety of [AWS-Specific Parameter Types](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html#aws-specific-parameter-types):

- `AWS::EC2::AvailabilityZone::Name`
- `AWS::EC2::Image::Id`
- `AWS::EC2::Instance::Id`
- `AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName`
- `AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::GroupName`
- `AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id`
- `AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id`
- `AWS::EC2::Volume::Id`
- `AWS::EC2::VPC::Id`
- `AWS::Route53::HostedZone::Id`
- `List<AWS::EC2::AvailabilityZone::Name>`
- `List<AWS::EC2::Image::Id>`
- `List<AWS::EC2::Instance::Id>`
- `List<AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::GroupName>`
- `List<AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id>`
- `List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>`
- `List<AWS::EC2::Volume::Id>`
- `List<AWS::EC2::VPC::Id>`
- `List<AWS::Route53::HostedZone::Id>`

Refer to the [Properties](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html#d0e17779) section of the [Parameters](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html) CloudFormation documentation for more detail.

<sub>Note that the documentation [linked](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack-parameters.html) to in the question was specifically regarding the [`Parameters`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack.html#cfn-cloudformation-stack-parameters) Property within the [`AWS::CloudFormation::Stack`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack.html) Resource, which is why the documentation was limited there. The [Template Anatomy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-anatomy.html) section of the guide has more complete information on template structure.</sub>